# Zabbix : Trigger Dependency not working Agent(Not reachable)-depends on>Proxy(Not reachable)

Tags: zabbix, zabbix-agent

We have proxy-agent relationship in which I want to make agent not reachable trigger to be dependent on proxy not reachable.

 Setup we have say for example : Zabb-Prxy(Proxy) monitors Zabb-Agnt(Agent).

I created two triggers as follows:
**On Zabb-Prxy Node: Have trigger "Agent not found for 3 minutes"** 

`Trigger Expression: {ip-10-4-1-28.ec2.internal:agent.ping.nodata(3m)}=1`

**On Zabb-Agnt Node:Have trigger "Agent not found for 5 minutes"** 

`Trigger Expression: {ip-10-4-1-11.ec2.internal:agent.ping.nodata(5m)}=1
---->Depends on Zabb-Prxy: Have trigger "Agent not found for 3 minutes"`

I used depedency option in the create trigger window for zabb-agent to configure it as dependent on proxy.

I am gettting why is not workig as expected I am getting notification mail for both the nodes It really frustrating.

Expected / Aim : If proxy is down I should get notification mail only
for proxy and not for agent.

I am referring to [this url](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/config/triggers/dependencies).

Actual: I am getting mail for both the node, Proxy is down and agent is down. 
I am not what I have missed or doing worngly. Need help
Even if someone let me know how I can debug it. That will save life.. 
Any help greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance.

Comment: (1) On Zabb-Prxy node, is the agent monitored by server or proxy? (2) When the proxy goes down, does the agent on Zabb-Prxy node go down, too?

Comment: No @asaveljevs . The Scenario is when I shutdown proxy service on zab-proxy node. Zabb-server thinks that nodes(monitored by zabb-proxy) is  also down though the agent process is running on them. Only proxy service is down on the zabb-proxy node

Comment: Zabbix trigger dependencies [are strange](https://www.zabbix.com/forum/showthread.php?t=48307).